# Remove wordpress admin menu area

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, admin

I am trying to completely remove the wp admin menu area for certain users/user-roles and make the content area full width. I managed to remove the admin menu via the colors.min.css file. I am assigning the individual users with a certain user role to a color scheme and make the menu invisible for these users. However the left frame is still there. I want to make the content area (with all the info about a blog, page or other content type) full with.

Is this something that can be achieved via css?

thanks in advance

Comment: First you should not change the basic setting of wp admin but if you want then inspect and check the parent div(sidebar) and then remove it or use display:none to remove that.

Comment: were can I find this div sidebar or in what file should i look? tnx for your answer..

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to hack the core WordPress files. Next time you update WordPress, all the changes that you've made will be overwritten.

Instead, add a new stylesheet to the site backend and add your CSS in that file.

The following CSS should achieve what you're looking for.

```
#wpcontent{
    display: none;
}
#wpcontent,
#wpfooter {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx. I understand not to edit the core files, however I need to remove, disable the admin area per user(role). I have created a child theme with a custom css. However the code you suggested does not remove the admin area. I want to remove the menu from the backend and have the content area full width

Comment: @Michel which user role will not be able to see the admin area?

Comment: I think you refer to the stylesheet that is enqueued in your site front-end as `custom css`. This will apply only to the front-end. 

As I already said, you'll have to enqueue a separate stylesheet for the site backend.

Comment: You'll have to hook to the [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) action.

Comment: Hi Hareesh.. sorry for the late respons.. Tnx, I have managed to load an css to control the backend. I have added the following to my functions.php: // Update CSS within in Admin
function admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');  The only thing I am looking now for is to apply this css file only to logged in users with a certain role.. Tnx

Comment: Hi Hareesh, I have manage"d to sort it out and am posting it for other users: // Update CSS within in Admin
function admin_style()
{    global $user_ID;
 
    if ( current_user_can( 'user_role' ) )
{  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style'); Tnx again for your help

Comment: I'm glad! Please add the code that you've posted here as a separate answer and mark it as the accepted solution, so that people who come here in search of a similar problem will find it useful.